# C# ASP.NET Repeater Sorting

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am for advice on how to go about carrying out sorting using a ASP.NET repeater.

Basically want the user be able to sort the repeated data by clicking on the headers fields.

Here is my repeater

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phOrders">    
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>          
      <th><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOrderBy" runat="server" Text="Order Number" OnClick="lnkOrderBy_Click"></asp:LinkButton></th>          
      <th><asp:linkButton ID="lnkOrderByItem" runat="server" Text="Item" OnClick="lnkOrderByIte_Click"></asp:linkButton></th>
      <th>Size</th>          
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>Status</th>          
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rprOrders" runat="server" >

      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td><strong><%# Eval("OrderDate") %></strong></td>
          <td><%# Eval("OrderItemSKUName") %></td>
          <td><%# Eval("OrderItemSKUID") %></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><%# Eval("OrderItemUnitCount") %></td>
          <td><strong><%# Eval("OrderItemStatus") %></strong></td>              
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="track-footer"></div>
 </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Should I store the data in a ViewState and then carry out sorting? Or query the database for each click events?

Here is my code for populating the repeater

```
private void PopulateOrders()
{

  CustomerInfo ki = CustomerInfoProvider.GetCustomerInfoByUserID(CooneenHelper.GetUserImpersonisationID());
  int nKustomerID = ki.CustomerID;
  DataTable dts = new DataTable();
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUName", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUID", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemStatus", typeof(string));
  dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemUnitCount", typeof(string));

  QueryDataParameters qdp = new QueryDataParameters();
  qdp.Add("@CustomerID", nKustomerID);
  DataSet ds = gc.ExecuteQuery("CN_OrderList", qdp, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure, true);

  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
    DataRow drNew = dts.NewRow();
    drNew["OrderDate"] = ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(dr["OrderDate"], DateTime.Now).ToShortDateString();
    drNew["OrderItemSKUName"] = dr["OrderItemSKUName"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemSKUID"] = dr["OrderItemSKUID"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemStatus"] = dr["OrderItemStatus"].ToString();
    drNew["OrderItemUnitCount"] = dr["OrderItemUnitCount"].ToString();
    dts.Rows.Add(drNew);
  }

  PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
  pds.DataSource = dts.DefaultView;
  DataView view = dts.DefaultView;

  //allow paging, set page size, and current page
  pds.AllowPaging = true;
  pds.PageSize = PerPage;
  pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

  //show # of current page in label
  if (pds.PageCount > 1) litResults.Text += " - Showing page " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + pds.PageCount.ToString();

  //disable prev/next buttons on the first/last pages
  btnPrev.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
  btnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;

  rprOrders.Visible = true;

  rprOrders.DataSource = pds;
  rprOrders.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: That is old asp.net? The one that is so terrible to integrate with client side code? I.e. not mvc? Is moving to modern technology (ASP.NET MVC) an option? That makes a lot easier and you could do things client side.

Comment: @TomTom MVC is not an option :(

Comment: have a look at this : http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/10/csharp-sorting-columns-in-repeater-control-in-aspnet.html

Comment: if you want to do it client side have a look at third party libraries to replace repeater e.g. https://datatables.net/

Comment: Hi Zaki thanks for the reply. The first link was helpful however I found a similar tutorial http://shravanti88.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/sorting-in-repeater.html however it doesn't work totally with my solution. Updating post.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I store the data in a ViewState and then carry out sorting?  Or query the database for each click events?

There's not one right answer - if you go back to the database you use network IO but you always get fresh data ,however that data may not match what you currently see on the screen.  Do some research on [ViewState vs Session vs Cache](https://www.google.com/search?q=ViewState+vs+Session+vs+Cache) to see which one meets your needs best.  Either one of those can store your data in a way that's easy to get back and let you sort it based on client input.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using Paging, that tells me that you are not concerned about the need to requery - so resorting from Session seems perfectly reasonable.**

The decision to requery the database (for sorting or any other reason) should be determined based on several factors:

- What is the likelihood that the data have changed (including adds and
  deletes) in between the time the user first saw the data and when
  they might choose to re-sort - or is it even important that they see
  the updates?
- Session is a per-user store.  Depending on how many rows each user is keeping in the server's memory, that could eventually tax the server.  What happens when Session expires?
- What is the cost (time, server processing power, etc) of requerying the data?

I don't know if this helps (especially with that last question) but you seem to be cycling through a DataTable (ds.Tables[0].Rows) and creating another DataTable (dts).  Is that processing really necessary?  It doesn't appear to be doing anything useful - but maybe that's just this example.  :)

In this code, I've commented out a bunch of things which don't appear to be necessary.  Feel free to bring them back if they make sense in the real situation.

I've also added a page-global variable (which you'll need to define) called isFirstTrip which you'll need to set to 1 on init or any time you need the database requeried (e.g., when the user does a new search?).

```
private void PopulateOrders()
{
  if (isFirstTrip == 1) 
  {
    CustomerInfo ki = CustomerInfoProvider.GetCustomerInfoByUserID(CooneenHelper.GetUserImpersonisationID());
    int nKustomerID = ki.CustomerID;
    /*
    DataTable dts = new DataTable();
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUName", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemSKUID", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemStatus", typeof(string));
    dts.Columns.Add("OrderItemUnitCount", typeof(string));
    */

    QueryDataParameters qdp = new QueryDataParameters();
    qdp.Add("@CustomerID", nKustomerID);
    session("OrderList") = gc.ExecuteQuery("CN_OrderList", qdp, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure, true);

    /*DataSet ds = gc.ExecuteQuery("CN_OrderList", qdp, QueryTypeEnum.StoredProcedure, true);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
      DataRow drNew = dts.NewRow();
      drNew["OrderDate"] = ValidationHelper.GetDateTime(dr["OrderDate"], DateTime.Now).ToShortDateString();
      drNew["OrderItemSKUName"] = dr["OrderItemSKUName"].ToString();
      drNew["OrderItemSKUID"] = dr["OrderItemSKUID"].ToString();
      drNew["OrderItemStatus"] = dr["OrderItemStatus"].ToString();
      drNew["OrderItemUnitCount"] = dr["OrderItemUnitCount"].ToString();
      dts.Rows.Add(drNew);
    }*/
  } 
  isFirstTrip = 0;
  PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
  pds.DataSource = DirectCast(session("OrderList"),DataTable).DefaultView;
  //pds.DataSource = dts.DefaultView;
  //DataView view = dts.DefaultView;  <- Not used

  //allow paging, set page size, and current page
  pds.AllowPaging = true;
  pds.PageSize = PerPage;
  pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

  //show # of current page in label
  if (pds.PageCount > 1) litResults.Text += " - Showing page " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + pds.PageCount.ToString();

  //disable prev/next buttons on the first/last pages
  btnPrev.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
  btnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;

  rprOrders.Visible = true;

  rprOrders.DataSource = pds;
  rprOrders.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do it via the session?

Comment: Basically, I've wrapped the bulk of your database code in an IF to check to see if this is the first time we're running through PopulateOrders and hit the database only that first time.  From then on, we use the copy from Session.  You may also want to overwrite Session("OrderList") with something small (like a zero-length string) when you're getting ready to leave the page so it doesn't stick around in memory for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks Steve Barron for the example. It makes much more sense now. However I am not sure how I can apply the above to sorting the data? I am trying to follow the example http://shravanti88.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/sorting-in-repeater.html?

Comment: In the click events of those column header linkbuttons, call PopulateOrders, with a new parameter indicating which column to sort by.  Replace pds.DataSource = DirectCast(session("OrderList"),DataTable).DefaultView; with pds.DataSource = New DataView(session("OrderList"),DataTable, "", SortByParameter,False);

Comment: Other things to consider...when you re-sort, it's probably a good idea to start from Page 1 again.   

In your Page_Load event, consider setting a default sort column (and order?) then keep track of it.  If the user clicks on OrderItemSKUName to sort and that is already the current sort order, consider sorting by the same column in reverse order, if that makes any sense to your users.